# how to manually render data from editor-js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, editorjs

I'm using editor.js for the first time, and I got stuck on this part: After selecting image from my gallery I want to re-render editor js with new image: this is my code for now

```
let url = `/${this.selectedImg.image.id}/${this.selectedImg.image.name}`
  this.editor.configuration.data.blocks.push({
    data: {
      caption: "",
      file: {url: url},
      stretched: false,
      withBackground: false,
      withBorder: false,
    },
    type: "image"
  })
  console.log(this.editor,'editor')
  this.editor.render()
```

but `this.editor.render()` doesn't work, what am I missing?
this is `console.log` [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhr6V.png)

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

```
 editor.save().then((data) => {
     data.blocks.push({
       type: "image",
       data: {
         caption: "",
         file: {url: url},
         stretched: false,
         withBackground: false,
         withBorder: false,
       },
     })
     this.editor.render(data)
     this.$emit('close', true)
   })
```

this was the answer, I misread the docs :)